# How to add custom script form admin in head or footer which call on every page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically i want to add script of google analytic script to my  store .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167553/magento-2-add-custom-script-just-after-head-tag

Answer (score 0):

Login to Magento 2 Admin,

on the Admin Panel, Stores > Settings > Configuration > Google API

Enable and configure the fields

[image: Login to Magento 2 Admin, on the Admin Panel, Stores > Settings > Configuration.]

Comment: what is the Anonymize ip and Enable Content Experiments?

Comment: By default it would be false in google analytics. If your privacy policy or local privacy laws prevent the storage of full IP addresses then you can use the IP anonymization feature to anonymize/mask website visitors IPs. For more info https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-turn-on-ip-anonymization-in-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager/

Comment: and what about the Enable Content Experiments?

Comment: As of now you can set it to "No" because Google Content Experiments has been deprecated.